# Particle system on sphere surface

Tags: unity, particles

I would like that particle system travels only on sphere surface.
I have set sphere and particle system as it's child.
How to constraint particle system ?

How to make trails follow along sphere surface?

[image]

On sphere it would look something like this

with trails:
[image]

without trails:
[image]

Comment: What kind of movement across the surface of the sphere do you have in mind? Do you want the particles to orbit with the same speed & direction, or each particle on its own orbit, or some other more complex behaviours?

Comment: Complex behaviours. For starters I would like PS travels along the surface and then I could set noise. I forgot to ask how to make trails follow along sphere surface?

Comment: Hmm, let's try a different angle: What's the final effect you want to achieve? Depending on what the end result is, there might be more suitable solutions than trying to bend a particle system to fit. Including a sketch, mock-up, or example of similar effects in existing games/TV/film may help clarify your goals.

Comment: I've updated the post. There are a lot of examples in movies and games. It would be to much to post it all. Did I described it well with sketch ?

Comment: How are you controlling this system? Does the user click on the surface of the sphere to get particles to move (there)? You're going to have to tell us more or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Hm, I didn't thought of this. Ok, user could trigger on surface click particle system. I want to give a sphere a slight transparent material.

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is *what **is** this sphere effect*? Is it the clouds in the atmosphere around a planet? Electric arcs around ball lightning? A deflector shield around a spaceship? The corona of a star? Moths spiraling around a lightbulb? We might use entirely different techniques for each one, so making your request concrete can help us narrow down the best tool for the job. You don't need to post every imaginable example, just one or two visual targets to make it unambiguous what it is that you want.

Comment: do the particles need to look 3d?

Comment: @DMGregory  A deflector shield is the closest one.

Comment: @CobaltHex what do you mean by that ? Partcle has default  additive material.

Comment: This isn't a guessing game where you tell us only when we're getting warmer. ;) The more up-front and clear you are about what you want to create, the better the answers you'll get.

Comment: You probably want to do this with a custom shader if the particles don't leave the surface if the sphere. It would be helpful though if you had some sort of example of the effect you see in a movie.

Comment: Tron legacy https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/da/e8/14/dae8149c339f2e1faa485a1807471bb3.jpg  and this one https://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marvelcinematicuniverse/images/e/e5/TesseractPortal.png/revision/latest?cb=20140930235436

Comment: Hello, should I  explain more ? Basically, I would like particles flowing in complex matter on surface of the sphere.